# Ampersands not being processed in scala xml

Tags: xml, scala

Im creating an XML replacement utility which will replace an attribute in an XML file. But for some reason if the attribute I'm trying to replace contains an ampersand, it doesn't get processed properly by a boolean method (isreplacementEntry) I wrote. My code is as follows

```
  /**
   * This method is used to iterate over the entirety of the xml presented and modify the XML attribute desired while
   * keeping old XML values
   * @param elem the XML you pass in (generally from file, input stream or string)
   * @param attrName name of the attribute you want to replace
   * @param curVal value of the current attribute
   * @return
   */
  def replaceXMLEntryAttribute(elem: Elem, attrName: String, curVal: String, desiredVal: String): Node = {
    def replace: Node => Node =
    {
      case e: Elem if isReplacementEntry(e, attrName, curVal) ⇒ generateReplacementXMLAttribute(e)
      case e: Elem ⇒ e.copy(
        child = e.child.map { replace(_) }
      )
      case other⇒ other
    }

    def generateReplacementXMLAttribute(node: Elem): Elem = {
      println("gets here")
      val currentXML= node.toString()
      val newAttr= currentXML.replaceAllLiterally("\""+curVal, "\""+desiredVal)

      XML.loadString(newAttr)

    }
    replace(elem)
  }

  /**
   * This method checks whether
   * @param node  The elements from which you wish to check if such an attribute exists
   * @param attributeName The name of the attribute to modify
   * @param currentAttrValue The current value of thr attribute that will eventually be modified
   * @return
   */
  private def isReplacementEntry(node: Elem, attributeName: String,  currentAttrValue: String): Boolean = {
  /*  val test = node.mkString)
    println(test)*/
    val attr = "@" + attributeName
    val exists = node \\ attr find { _.text == currentAttrValue }
    exists match{
      case None => false
      case _ => true
    }
  }
```

Specifically, this line  `val exists = node \\ attr find { _.text == currentAttrValue }` always returns false. Something I tried was using scala.xml.Utility.escape with current Attr Value but it still doesnt seem to work.

Sample XML this should work with is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Stuff expression="test">
<Rule expression="threshold &lt;= 20 AND '${userID}' IN ('USER1','USER2','USER_7','USER_09')"/>
</Stuff>
```

where I'm trying to replace the line with Rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is probably that you are looking for a wrong string. Ampersands in XML signify a start of a character reference, and when you call `elem.text`, they get replaced with the corresponding character. Try running the following line in Scala console: `<foo attr="&lt;"/> \@ "attr"`. It results in the string `<`.

So for the given XML the arguments should look like this:

```
replaceXMLEntryAttribute(
  yourXml, 
  "expression", 
  "threshold <= 20 AND '${userID}' IN ('USER1','USER2','USER_7','USER_09')", 
  "some new value")
```

That still won't be enough, because you replace the value literally in the serialized string representation of XML, which *has* those ampresands. So even if you've found some attribute in `isReplacementEntry`, it won't get replaced in `generateReplacementXMLAttribute`. Instead it would probably be easier and safer to use the attribute replacement operator `%` on the element:

```
def generateReplacementXMLAttribute(node: Elem): Elem = 
  node % xml.Attribute(attrName, xml.Text(desiredVal), xml.Null)
```

But then the problem is that this would replace only the direct attributes of its argument, but in `isReplacementEntry` you match with `\\`, so it would return `true` if *any* descendant element has the attribute with the required value. Instead it should be `true` only if the element has its own attribute with this value:

```
private def isReplacementEntry(node: Elem, attributeName: String,  currentAttrValue: String): Boolean = 
  node \@ attributeName == currentAttrValue
```

So here is the full working version of the code (without Scaladoc). Note that the value you want to search for should have the character references replaced with the actual characters:

```
def replaceXMLEntryAttribute(elem: Elem, attrName: String, curVal: String, desiredVal: String): Node = {
  def replace: Node => Node = {
    case e: Elem if isReplacementEntry(e, attrName, curVal) ⇒
      generateReplacementXMLAttribute(e)
    case e: Elem ⇒ e.copy(child = e.child map replace)
    case other ⇒ other
  }

  def generateReplacementXMLAttribute(node: Elem): Elem =
    node % xml.Attribute(attrName, xml.Text(desiredVal), xml.Null)

  replace(elem)
}

private def isReplacementEntry(node: Elem, attributeName: String,  currentAttrValue: String): Boolean =
  node \@ attributeName == currentAttrValue

println(replaceXMLEntryAttribute(
  <Stuff expression="test">
    <Rule expression="threshold &lt;= 20 AND '${userID}' IN ('USER1','USER2','USER_7','USER_09')"/>
  </Stuff>, 
  "expression", 
  "threshold <= 20 AND '${userID}' IN ('USER1','USER2','USER_7','USER_09')", 
  "foobar"))
```

Comment: In running your code, I receive the following error:value \@ is not a member of scala.xml.Elem

Comment: Ah yes, checking the scala doc for Version 2.10.2 indicates this wasnt implemented yet

Comment: @Zee Well, you can replace `(elem: Elem) \@ attr` with `(elem \ ("@" + attr)).text`